# Swift: order of function completion is unpredictable

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ipad

I'm getting unpredictable results and I'd like to understand why. I'm calling two functions. The first time, the second function completes first, but after that, it works and they complete in order. I'm new to Swift, so I'm lost.

Here are the two calls:

```
 updateValue(value: row, picker: picker.tag)
 updateResult()
```

updateValue calls a web service that writes data using:

```
...
     NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue()) {(response, data, error) -> Void in
            if error != nil {
            println("error")
            } else {
            println(response)
            }
...
```

then updateResult reads the data also using a web service call.

```
...
    var task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {
            (data, response, error) -> Void in
...
```

Since updateValue is asynchronous (and I've read here that's the way it should be), I'm not sure what I should do. And I'm also confused as to why it only fails on the first use. If the order is unpredictable, why is the behaviour so predictable?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Now I *may* be wrong but it looks to me that `sendAsynchronousRequest` could very well be an async call :-)

In other words, if farms off the task to another "thread" of execution and may indeed return to you before the actual work is done.

If you want synchronous behaviour, you're probably better off calling it synchronously or at least waiting until the async operation is finished before performing the dependent step (with a `completionHandler` for example).

Comment: I'll set aside that you started by making fun of me. :)  since completion handler sounds like a good idea. I'll try that

Comment: Apologies,@user3026206, was mildly poking fun at the question rather than you personally. That's just the bizarre Aussie wit, such as it is.